# Jersey resource not resolving in OSGI

Tags: jersey, jetty, osgi, jax-rs, bndtools

I have been following this [tutorial video](http://amdatu.org/howto/createwebapp.html) which shows how to run a <s>jersey server</s>(**EDIT:** A JAX-RS server via Apache Wink, see accepted answer) in OSGI.  It is a short video and the process seems mostly very clear.  What I'm not clear on is how exactly the HelloWorldResource is loaded into Jersey.  The HelloWorldResource is registered into OSGI container as a service using Apache Felix DependencyActivatorBase (which works great).  From what I gather Apache Felix Whiteboard is supposed to somehow magically map that as a Jersey Resource, but when I go to run it I get 404.

I know the service is mapped correctly as it shows up in the console when I issue the 'services' command.  I know the server is running or I wouldn't get a 404 not found.  I've double checked the bundles and believe all are installed correctly.

Any hints appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, Amdatu is not based on Jersey. Jersey is one of the many JAX-RS implementations available. Amdatu is based on Apache Wink. This shouldn't really matter to you however, since you should be programming to the standard anyway.

Amdatu looks for services registered as Object.class in the service registry, and checks if the registered service is annotated with the @Path annotation. If this is the case, the service is registered as a JAX-RS resource. This way the development model is very similar to using JAX-RS in a Java EE environment.

You can install the Apache Felix Dependency Manager Shell bundle to debug services registered using DM. Type the following command in the shell: `dm <bundleid>`.
This will list all registered services by that bundle. You should see the service registered as java.lang.Object. Do the same for the bundle id of the org.amdatu.web.rest.wink bundle. You should see something like this for your service: javax.servlet.Servlet(init.applicationConfigLocation=/conf/application.properties,alias=/somepath,init.requestProcessorAttribute=/somepath) registered.

Also check if you are looking at the correct URL. By default, RESTful resources in Amdatu are registered to the root path (e.g. 'localhost:8080/myresource').

Comment: The key for me was making sure wink and the whiteboard were being loaded.  If Wink is just a JAX-RS impl, then why wouldn't Amdatu register the resource if I just dropped in jersey-server instead of Wink?

Comment: Fair question. Unfortunately the programmatic API to register resources from code is not standardised in JAX-RS, so there is some implementation specific code required.

Comment: I've had a 404 as well with this demo, but happend because two Jetty bundles where deployed. (2.2.2 and 2.2.0) 2.2.2 was located in my localrepo and manually placed it in the 'Run requirements' block. The other (2.2.0) was resolved with the Bnd tools 'resolve' button and downloaded from the BndTools Hub. According to the resolve dialog the 2.2.0 was required by the whiteboard bundle. Can this be a bug in Bnd tools? Because I think both Jetty bundles where valid.